# RL circuit analysis

Tags: circuit-analysis, inductor

This is an exercise in my final assignment:

[image: My exercise]

According to some of my searches, the voltage source that has negative value is connected to the ground. Therefore, my idea is to connect R1, R3, R4 and L but I don't know how to do it properly. I'm new in this area so please help me. Any help will be appreciated.
Regards,

Answer (score 1):

Two hints:

1. The state of the circuit to the left of the switch before the switch closes is irrelevant to solving the problem.
2. After the switch closes, you can simplify the rest of the circuit (4 resistors and a 20 V source) to a single Thevenin equivalent circuit.

Comment: I'm still not clearly understand about the -8V source, can you explain it for me, thanks.

Comment: @SơnTùng You can assume there is a voltage source forcing that node to -8 V at all times.

Comment: Does that means I just need to ignore that source when I simplify the circuit?

Comment: I redraw the circuit after the switch is closed and it looks like this: https://scontent.fsgn2-4.fna.fbcdn.net/v/t1.15752-9/42445881_310401286211153_9031695759627517952_n.jpg?_nc_cat=101&oh=c1c61e768a733b263e74f4f719c34c78&oe=5C1501A6

Comment: @SơnTùng, no that's not correct. You might want to go back to studying how to find the Thevenin equivalent of a source/resistor network, which you should have learned before learning about inductor or capacitor circuits.